How to better understand and reverse-engineer system calls within processes given a specific example
I am very new to linux and as such would appreciate any pointers with respect to understanding system calls and having the ability, knowledge and tools to reverse-engineer their origin or their process flow.
As the title suggests, i present an example, being my analysis of an Xorg process that i traced in my linux desktop environment. As such, i am attempting to understand the process flow of DRM_IOCTL calls, in this case a specific DRM_IOCTL_CURSOR2 system call that takes place within the process. My goal is to understand what triggers this call within this desktop environment, or rather what steps I can take in general to investigate inquiries like this
From my limited understanding I am aware that Xorg is spawned as a subprocess of SDDM but aside from initiating the Xorg server, I am at a blank in trying to figure out how to walk through the process and  identify triggers for certain process calls or perhaps the use of tools to do so. As such this is a conceptual question on how to approach analyses such as this in general. Would this require specific knowledge of the process at hand and its architecture. Would there be any general approaches I can take on my system to trace systemcalls much like deducing ppids of processes for my own interest.
As of now I have vague familiarity using tools like strace, bpftrace and general command line tools like ps & lsof. Apologies if this is a broad question, if so I will be happy to narrow it further

Yep, that sounds good: bpftrace to figure out how often some syscall is made, and by whom, as well as strace to figure out which syscalls a specific process makes. Got a significant part!
The next part is actually figuring out which functions in your process are doing the syscalls – and the only way to do that is by attaching a debugger.
The default debugger on Linux is gdb. Let's walk you through it.
Prerequisite (for now): Having debug symbols for your process. That's easy if you built something yourself and have debug symbols included (but then, what are you reverse engineering); it's easy if you can use your system's facilities to download debug information for you. I like that Fedora (and other major Linux distros like debian or Ubuntu) offer debuginfod symbols, that makes this walkthrough a lot easier.

Install gdb.
Set the environment variable telling gdb where to find debuginfod data (optional, but makes things a lot more readable for a start; adjust URL for your distro):
export DEBUGINFOD_URLS=https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/about-debuginfod


find the Process ID (pid) of the process you want to work with (e.g. using bpftrace)
attach gdb to that PID: gdb --pid the_pid_you_care_about. At this point, it might need to download a lot of debug info.
tell gdb to catch all syscalls that are ioctls and then continue running:
(gdb) catch syscall ioctl
(gdb) continue


you'd get thrown back to the gdb interface every time an ioctl is caused; at which point you can do things like backtrace to see the call stack including function names, and print variables from the current stack frame (if they haven't been optimized out by the compiler)
you can detach from the process or quit (and kill it)

Anyways, the way 5. works is kind of annoying: you actually don't want to break at every ioctl, only at ioctls with specific arguments, and you don't really want to break either, you want to do a backtrace and log that to a file, maybe. So, instead of 4. you could do:
(gdb) set logging on
(gdb) set logging file ~/mylog.txt
(gdb) catch syscall ioctl
(gdb) commands
backtrace
continue
end
(gdb) continue

Of course, the situation where you have debug symbols is very luxurious, but for a start, let's not make our life worse than has to ^^.
If you encounter a program for which you can't get debug symbols, you'd probably do a combination of life debugging, disassembling, stepping through, and giving memory addresses names, e.g. in the rather capable ghidra tool.

Thats a great wealth of info Marcus thank you for your time and effort in writing and producing your response . I was struggling with finding debug symbols and had no idea where to look as well. I will put the steps to practice and look further at using tools like ghidra; Appreciate your insight and knowledge in this end. I had briefly used gdb but did not pursue it further at the time;Its a different mindset Coming from a GUI environment of tools like windows (WinDBG,Sysinternals)

Oh, there's graphical frontends to gdb as well. People speak positively of debugging with VS Code (though I personally never tried that), and there's many others as well.

Awesome ill definitely look into that. I think alot of my issues also stem from a lack of understanding of the specific architecture of process bundles so trying to learn some basics. Currently just trying to debug some processes in the desktop environment cause i'm noticing strange behaviour with my input processes. Thought it'd be  a good way to learn some fundementals of linux debugging. Kudos again for the insights really appreciated!
